# TokensRegex throws exception

Tags: regex

I have the following regex that is working partially and need help to make it work for all my use cases.

Regex:

```
([{word:/by/}][{tag:NN}]+)(/and|,/[{tag:NN}|{tag:VBG}]*)*
```

The above expression works fine for the following:

```
by market and shipping
by market, shipping and region
```

However, the regex will fail for the following:

```
by market
```

Can anyone help me writing the correct regex.

Updated:

Following is the stack trace for the exception:

[pool-1-thread-7] INFO CoreNLP - [/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:64476] API call w/annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,regexner,parse,depparse,natlog,mention,coref,openie,kbp
by market
[pool-1-thread-7] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[pool-1-thread-7] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
[pool-1-thread-7] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator pos
[pool-1-thread-7] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator lemma
[pool-1-thread-7] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ner
[pool-1-thread-7] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator regexner
[pool-1-thread-7] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator parse
[pool-1-thread-7] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator depparse
[pool-1-thread-7] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator natlog
[pool-1-thread-7] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator mention
[pool-1-thread-7] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator coref
[pool-1-thread-7] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator openie
[pool-1-thread-7] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator kbp
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer$TokensRegexHandler.lambda$null$365(StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:814)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.JSONOutputter$JSONWriter.object(JSONOutputter.java:453)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.JSONOutputter$JSONWriter.routeObject(JSONOutputter.java:352)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.JSONOutputter$JSONWriter.lambda$object$344(JSONOutputter.java:467)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer$TokensRegexHandler.lambda$null$366(StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:808)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.JSONOutputter$JSONWriter.object(JSONOutputter.java:453)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.JSONOutputter$JSONWriter.routeObject(JSONOutputter.java:352)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.JSONOutputter$JSONWriter.routeObject(JSONOutputter.java:330)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.JSONOutputter$JSONWriter.routeObject(JSONOutputter.java:354)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.JSONOutputter$JSONWriter.lambda$object$344(JSONOutputter.java:467)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer$TokensRegexHandler.lambda$null$368(StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:803)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.JSONOutputter$JSONWriter.object(JSONOutputter.java:453)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.JSONOutputter$JSONWriter.object(JSONOutputter.java:474)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.JSONOutputter$JSONWriter.objectToJSON(JSONOutputter.java:500)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer$TokensRegexHandler.lambda$handle$369(StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:795)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Which exception are you getting? Can you share the stack trace?

Comment: Which programming environment?

Comment: I have just tried it and got a `by market` match. Are you sure it does not get matched on your end? What is the string you try it against?

Comment: I get the exception when trying to match by market. Here is the stack trace.